# hide on one click, show on another,

Tags: jquery

This is my html:

```
 <span class="sb-icon-search">Suche
    <img src="img/close_search.png" width="20" height="20" id="close_search">
 </span>
```

CSS:

```
#close_search {
 position: absolute;
 top: 26%;
 right: 20%;
 opacity: 0.4;
 visibility:hidden;
 }
```

`.sb-icon-search` is clickable.
When this button is clicked once, I need to make `#close_search` appear. On another click, it should disappear again... Long story short, I would like to change the `visibility` of the image on every click on `.sb-icon-search`

I tried this, but it only works once:

```
  jQuery(function($) { 
               $(".sb-icon-search").one('click', function(){
                   if (($(".sb-icon-search").length > 0)){ 
               $("#close_search").css('visibility','hidden');
               } else {
                 $("#close_search").css('visibility','visible'); 
               }
                                   });
                                 });
```

I've already tried some other functions (toggleClass etc.) but surprisingly none of them worked. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: if you use one() ... it will obviously work only on the first click ... you need to listen to the click event (either with on() or click()) and toggle the class with toggleClass()

Answer (score 0):

Can use [**toggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

```js
$('.sb-icon-search').click(function(){
     $(this).find('#close_search').toggle("slow");
});
```

```css
#close_search {
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    right: 2px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="sb-icon-search">Suche
    <img src="img/close_search.png" width="20" height="20" id="close_search">
 </span>
```

Comment: "slow"? Is this supposed to be a class?

Comment: "slow" is the effect. You can also put in "fade" , "slide", or my favorite "explode". If you leave it empty there is no effect applied to the showing and hiding of the element and it just appears or disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make use of jquery.data()
and here is a example

```
jQuery(
function($) { 
               $(".sb-icon-search").click(function(){



            $(".sb-icon-search").data('clicked','once');

               if (($(".sb-icon-search").data('clicked'))   ==  "once" ){ 

                    $("#close_search").css('visibility','hidden');
                } else {

                    $("#close_search").css('visibility','visible'); 
                }
                $(".sb-icon-search").data('clicked','');
                               });

                             });
```